# mc.cores > 1 is not support on windows

Tags: r, windows, parallel-processing, multicore

[image]I am new in R programming and I have code like below and I know that the windows does not support multicore but I don't know how to change this part of the code.
Can someone suggest me an equivalent code without using the mc.cores feature?

```
rpl <- unlist( lapply( waydf$geometry$coordinates , nrow ) ) # row per line
 waydf <- waydf[ rpl > 1 , ]
ll <- parallel::mclapply( waydf$geometry$coordinates , st_linestring,
                         mc.cores =parallel::detectCores() - 1  )
outdf <- sf::st_sf(
line_geometry = sf::st_sfc( ll , crs = epsg ) ,
osm_id = waydf$id
)
```

Comment: What is `st_linestring`? A custom function?

Comment: You *know* that Windows doesn't support multicore? It's *forking* that's not used because it's orders of magnitude slower than *multicore* processing. Forking starts a separate single-thread process. Using multiple *threads* on the same data is a lot faster. Try Revolution R's distribution which uses *real* multicore and SIMD processing. You'll find that `svd` on an i7 (quad) will be 7 times faster

Comment: Are you really asking how to do parallel processing on Windows? That's what the answer below tries to answer. Or do you just want to change this code to run not in parallel?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If all you want to do is make it so this code doesn't run in parallel, you just need to tell it to use 1 core, then it will use `lapply` under the hood.

```
ll <- parallel::mclapply(waydf$geometry$coordinates, st_linestring, mc.cores = 1)
```

Or just swap `mclapply` out for `lapply`.

```
ll <- lapply(waydf$geometry$coordinates, st_linestring)
```

Answer (score 6):

You'll have to clarify what `st_linestring` is or does because you're trying to pass the contents of `waydf$geometry$coordinates` to it, but haven't specified any arguments, such as `st_linestring(waydf$geometry$coordinates[i])`

In Windows, you would use `parLapply` instead of `mclapply`.

```
# original
ll <- parallel::mclapply( waydf$geometry$coordinates , st_linestring,
                         mc.cores =parallel::detectCores() - 1  )

# replace the above with all of the below
library(parallel)
cl <- makeCluster(detectCores())
cl <- clusterEvalQ(cl, { library(sf) })  # you need to export packages as well
# cl <- clusterExport(cl, "st_linestring")  # each worker is a new environment, you will need to export variables/functions to
ll <- parallel::parLapply(cl, waydf$geometry$coordinates, function(i) st_linestring)    # if st_linestring takes arguments then st_linestring(x)
stopCluster(cl)
```

**Edit** since st_linestring is a function from the package sf, it is sufficient to export sf

**2nd edit**

```
rpl <- unlist( lapply( waydf$geometry$coordinates , nrow ) ) # row per line
 waydf <- waydf[ rpl > 1 , ]

library(parallel)
cl <- makeCluster(detectCores())
cl <- clusterEvalQ(cl, { library(sf) })  # you need to export packages as well
# cl <- clusterExport(cl, "st_linestring")  # each worker is a new environment, you will need to export variables/functions to
ll <- parallel::parLapply(cl, waydf$geometry$coordinates, function(i) st_linestring)    # if st_linestring takes arguments then st_linestring(x)
stopCluster(cl)

outdf <- sf::st_sf(
line_geometry = sf::st_sfc( ll , crs = epsg ) ,
osm_id = waydf$id
)
```

Comment: I do still get the same error :(. how can I run this function without multicore feature?

Comment: Sorry, but did you replace `mclapply` with `parLapply`? What is your error? Please show

Comment: Error in makeCluster(detectCores()) : 
  could not find function "makeCluster"

Comment: now , i got this error: Error in checkCluster(cl) : not a valid cluster  in this line:                              cl <- parallel::clusterExport(cl, "st_linestring")

Comment: Since `st_linestring` is in `sf` package, you do not need to export it. I commented out the line

Comment: this is the new error: Error in detectCores() : could not find function "detectCores"

Comment: YEs, I loaded the parallel and the problem of detectingCores is solved. But I get again not a valid cluster error in the last line :  Error in checkCluster(cl) : not a valid cluster

Comment: could you please how can I run this code without parallelizing? in a very simple way.

Comment: I'm assuming *your* code works. You can replace `mclapply` with the answer provided above (see after the 2nd edit). I recommend you start a new R session before running this code.

Comment: I added a picture of my code with the error. I have no idea why do I still get this error.

Comment: Did you start a new R session? My guess is that you loaded a cluster before using `doMC`. And could you type `cl` and show the output?

Comment: You should see something like `socket cluster with 8 nodes on host ‘localhost’` when typing `cl`

Comment: yes, I restart a new R session each time I change the code.

Answer (score 1):

The problem is that you do `cl <- ...` in all those rows; you keep redefining that variable to be something else.  You should only assign `cl` once and then reuse it.

```
library("parallel")
cl <- makeCluster(detectCores())
clusterEvalQ(cl, { library("sf") })
clusterExport(cl, "st_linestring")
res <- parallel::parLapply(cl, X = waydf$geometry$coordinates, 
                         fun = function(i) st_linestring)
stopCluster(cl)
```

The message `Error in checkCluster(cl): not a valid cluster` that you get with your code is because after you do `cl <- clusterEvalQ(cl, { library("sf") })` it is no longer a `cluster` object.

Comment: @ HenrikB, hey. thanks for the answer. I tried to run your code but i got this error: Error in get(name, envir = envir) : object 'st_linestring' not found